# Optimisation to find combinations at less time in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, online-compilation

I have the following piece of code which finds whether any 4 combination in the list sums up to a value(say 7) is possible.If possible it prints 1 else 0.
it takes the:- number of list element(n) , list(test) and the number which needs to be checked(say 7)(x here).

Every time I execute it on any online platform it shows "**Time limit exceeded**".
How I can optimize it below 0.87s??Provided I have used "**itertools**" here.Where I am doing it wrong.

```
import itertools
t=int(input())
while t!=0:
    n=int(input())
    test=[int(val) for val in input().strip().split()]
    x=int(input())
    generator=(itertools.combinations(test,4))
    for elem in generator:
        val=elem
        if sum(val)==x:
            flag=1
            break
            break
    if not flag:
        print('0')
    else:
        print('1')
    t=t-1
```

Comment: Rather than maually looping through values, have you looked into `any()` or `all()`?

Comment: Where is `n` used in this code?

Comment: And why does `test` need to be computed on every iteration?

Comment: What are some of the lists and values you're testing with?  I think you should separate your inputs from your processing, so first get input for t, then secondly keep looping for inputs until the user sends 'q' ( or something), and then pass both t and list to your logic.

Comment: Are the numbers always positive? If so, you should not use `itertools.combinations` since it unnecessarily generates all possible combinations. You should write your own generator that short-circuits the search when the 3 or less numbers you have already reaches 7.

Comment: How to build my own generator in this case can u give a hint?